# How to submit a job to any [subset] of nodes from nodelist in SLURM?

Tags: cluster-computing, batch-processing, slurm, sbatch

I have a couple of thousand jobs to run on a SLURM cluster with 16 nodes. These jobs should run only on a subset of the available nodes of size 7. Some of the tasks are parallelized, hence use all the CPU power of a single node while others are single threaded. Therefore, multiple jobs should run at the same time on a single node. None of the tasks should spawn over multiple nodes.

Currently I submit each of the jobs as follow:

```
sbatch --nodelist=myCluster[10-16] myScript.sh
```

However this parameter makes slurm to wait till the submitted job terminates, and hence leaves 3 nodes completely unused and, depending on the task (multi- or single-threaded), also the currently active node might be under low load in terms of CPU capability.

What are the best parameters of `sbatch` that force slurm to run multiple jobs at the same time on the specified nodes?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can work the other way around; rather than specifying which nodes to use, with the effect that each job is allocated all the 7 nodes, specify which nodes not to use:

```
sbatch --exclude=myCluster[01-09] myScript.sh
```

and Slurm will never allocate more than 7 nodes to your jobs. Make sure though that the cluster configuration allows node sharing, and that your `myScript.sh` contains `#SBATCH --ntasks=1 --cpu-per-task=n` with `n` the number of threads of each job.

**Update**: since version 23.02, the `--nodelist` may contain more nodes than specified by `--nodes`. From the [changelog](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/master/NEWS):

> -- Allow for --nodelist to contain more nodes than required by --nodes.

Comment: This assuming you are not the administrator. Otherwise limits and associations are the way to go.

Comment: With 'associations' do you mean 'reservations' in SLURM vocabulary?

Comment: No I mean [associations](http://slurm.schedmd.com/accounting.html) which is term Slurm uses in the context of accounts, quality of services, partitions, etc. to set limits.

Comment: I am having trouble with the syntax `=myCluster[01-09]` :(  which are the distinct node names in this case?

Comment: `--exclude=myCluster[01-09]`  is equivalent to `--exclude=myCluster01,myCluster02,myCluster03,myCluster04,myCluster05,myCluster07,myCluster08,myCluster09,myCluster10,`.

Comment: @damienfrancois is it possible to get the name of the nodes as in PBS. i.e. do the equivalent `cat $PBS_NODEFILE > machinefile`

Comment: The variable `SLURM_JOB_NODELIST` holds the list of nodes. (not the path to a file that contains the list of nodes)

Answer (score 3):

> Some of the tasks are parallelized, hence use all the CPU power of a single node while others are single threaded.

I understand that you want the single-threaded jobs to share a node, whereas the parallel ones should be assigned a whole node exclusively?

> multiple jobs should run at the same time on a single node.

As far as my understanding of SLURM goes, this implies that you must define CPU cores as consumable resources (i.e., `SelectType=select/cons_res` and `SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core` in `slurm.conf`)

Then, to constrain parallel jobs to get a whole node you can either use [`--exclusive`](http://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html#OPT_exclusive) option (but note that partition configuration takes precedence: you can't have shared nodes if the partition is configured for exclusive access), or use `-N 1 --tasks-per-node="number_of_cores_in_a_node"` (e.g., `-N 1 --ntasks-per-node=8`).

Note that the latter will only work if all nodes have the same number of cores.

> None of the tasks should spawn over multiple nodes.

This should be guaranteed by `-N 1`.

Comment: Crucial is that all my jobs use in total not more than 7 nodes. Each node of our cluster has 20 cores and 2 threads per core.
If I understand you correctly you propose to submit parallel jobs with `sbatch --nodelist=myCluster[10-16] --ntasks-per-node=40 -N 1 myScript.sh`. Why not `--ntasks-per-node=1`, to make sure that not more than one job runs at the same time on a single node?
What about the single threaded jobs?

Comment: @Faber If you want to confine a set of jobs to use a maximum of 7 nodes in total, than a partition or a QoS setting would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think the way to go is setting up a '**reservation**' first. According to this presentation http://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm_ug_2011/Advanced_Usage_Tutorial.pdf (last slide).

*Scenario: Reserve ten nodes in the default SLURM partition starting at noon and with a duration of 60 minutes occurring daily. The reservation will be available only to users alan and brenda.*

```
scontrol create reservation user=alan,brenda starttime=noon duration=60 flags=daily nodecnt=10
Reservation created: alan_6

scontrol show res
ReservationName=alan_6 StartTime=2009-02-05T12:00:00
    EndTime=2009-02-05T13:00:00 Duration=60 Nodes=sun[000-003,007,010-013,017] NodeCnt=10 Features=(null) PartitionName=pdebug Flags=DAILY Licenses=(null)
    Users=alan,brenda Accounts=(null)

# submit job with:
sbatch --reservation=alan_6 myScript.sh
```

Unfortunately I couldn't test this procedure, probaly due to a lack of privileges.

Comment: A reservation will prevent *any other user from running* on the same set of nodes, that's why an admin is needed to create it.  Is this what you really want?  Reserve nodes for your exclusive access?

Comment: Well that's what we agreed on among the (few) users. If we can set a max duration, why not? Or is this approach a complete anti-pattern for cluster usage?

Comment: Is it possible give regular users permission to set up reservations?